# Making a simple 555 sawtooth VCO stable?

Tags: oscillator, 555, vco

I have figured out how to make a sawtooth VCO using a 555 IC , by using a current mirror.

The issues I am having is I can't make it stable at all. Its having random issues like it randomly changes frequency output or if I turn it off for awhile then back on it changes frequency output even if the input voltage on the current mirror stays the same.

So what components can I add to this circuit to make it stable enough? I need this circuit to be able to be able to keep the same frequency output with the same voltage input.

[image]

Comment: What frequency you want? Why use a 555 instead of an actual VCO?

Comment: @justme , I only need frequencies between  50 hz to  200 hz. Why not use a actual VCO: I am trying to make a really simple DIY VCO.

Comment: Define "stable enough".  Engineers like to work with real specifications, not vague descriptions. Also, keep in mind that the 555 was never intended as a precision oscillator.

Comment: The circuitry looks ok. Current mirror works well, and 555 is a good proven device. What is the connection between out & ctl for? That will make it hard to hit trig, and will be noisy. Remove that and try.

Comment: @jay That makes sure, the sawtooth output goes to ground, if the control input and the input isn't connected using a diode, the entire sawtooth output will float above ground.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser, And that breaks the operation. What you need to have is not that low trig voltage, but a voltage shift stage. Listen, and try what I said.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser What peak output voltage do you expect to achieve? Right to the +15 V rail? Or less? What's the spec? Also, how repeatable do you need this to be? That's not only a question about a single build. But also about building up more than one of these and comparing their outputs for the same input voltage.

Comment: @Jay , also technically not adding the diode to the control and output makes it more unstable for me.

Comment: @jonk The voltage doesn't need to be to the rail , and I am only making one of them, so it doesn't need to repeatable.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser One rigorous idea is to use a crystal oscillator and use that to run a counter (say, a 12-bit counter) that drives a ladder. Doesn't need a current source, that way. An MCU would be another approach (which is what I'd probably use.) But there you need software toolsets and software coding. Another is to use a voltage to current converter. I do this all the time with a single opamp and some BJTs for an precision 2-quadrant current source/sink. But you'd need a comparator like the LTC1540 (built-in ref) to periodically generate a short reset pulse. I would not use a 555.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser, that ("not adding the diode to the control and output makes it more unstable for m") to be the story, something else went wrong. look at [NE555 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf), page 5, TRIG voltage level min = 1.1V, while your trig V is 0.45V. There is a reason for that. The internal comparator input cannot detect  that low voltage signal reliably. You must have more than one incorrect wiring. The power could be unstable as well.

Comment: @jay I am sure , it is correct and I made the circuit like the above diagram I have shown, but though , I did switch to using a 9v battery,  but that was before I made this post. It might just be in my head that I think using the diode on the control voltage and output makes it more stable. Obviously because the stability is being random , it could have been just that one time , it was more stable with the diode.

Answer (score 1):

As shown the current mirror will be very sensitive to temperature variations. Even the self-heating due to the dissipation in the transistors will cause their temperature to change enough to cause unbalance between the two transistors. That is probably why you notice the change when it has been switched off for a while.

They should be matched and both be at exactly the same temperature, for example clamped together into a common heatsink.

The imbalance can be improved by putting a resistor in the emitter of each of the transistors. The value should be selected so that it drops a few hundred millivolts or more. In that circuit there is about 300uA flowing in the first transistor so a 1 kilohm resistor would be a good place to start. An example is shown below.

What type of capacitor are you using for the timing? A ceramic capacitor such as X7R is probably not good enough for temperature stability. A film capacitor would be better.

[image]

Comment: The addition of emitter degeneration, right at the level you mention, is good to do. That's still got the Early Effect to worry over. The addition of a cascoded device will help that. (There are a few other ideas to add, but that's the larger problem.)

Comment: @jonk - emitter degeneration will help with Early effect as well because it will reduce the effect of the base-emitter voltage changes.

Comment: Agreed. I haven't yet calculated how much is removed by what allowed degeneration overhead voltage. Have you done that, yet?

Answer (score 0):

A current mirror is great on paper, but it rarely works well with real-world components.  Every parameter about a transistor, including its gain and base-emitter junction voltage, is either temperature-dependent, collector-current-dependent, or both.

Commercially available VCO IC's have a lot going on internally, and a lot of that is compensating and offsetting circuits hovering around the main VCO structure.

Linear Technology and Texas Instruments have many app notes on opamp circuit design, with sections on VCO's.  IIRC these are not "simple" circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Add some emitter degenration to the current mirror to improve its stability. (perhaps 3.3K in series with each emitter - you have plenty of headroom)

The trick you're pulling on the control-voltage pin is defeating the 555s internal ripple rejection strategy. you may want to reconsider that. perhaps restore the ripple rejection capacitor on pin 5 and use a comparitor to drive the trigger pin if you don't like a trigger level of VCC/3

Use a high stability capacitor such as polystyrene film for the timing capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

When the DIS pin is driven low it is forced to sink a very high current for a very short time as it discharges the timing capacitor. You could try putting a small resistor, say 100R, in series with the DIS pin to limit the discharge current. Note that adding the extra resistor will slightly increase the slope of the vertical drops of the output waveform.

If that doesn't improve matters then you could try the circuit below.

The op amp and its associated resistors form a level shifter. It also doubles the amplitude of the output waveform compared to your circuit. If the amplitude is too big for you then you can reduce it by adding a resistive potential divider at the output. The frequency is about 125 Hz, as you can see.

[image: Saw tooth waveform generator]

Comment: weirdly if I try this in spice it doesn't go to ground for me, for some reason it slightly floats above ground if the op amp is grounded , if the op amp has both positive and negative rails , the sawtooth goes positive and negative.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser The LM358's output will not quite reach ground when its negative supply rail is ground, but it should get within a few 10s of millivolts of ground. If you use plus and minus supplies for the LM358 make sure that the bottom end of R4 (and the rest of the circuit) is still connected to ground (0V).

Comment: @MichaelWeaser Accuracy of my circuit's output depends on the 555's internal thresholds being 1/3 and 2/3 of Vcc. The thresholds will probably not be spot on those values which will lead to a dc offset at the output. You could adjust any dc error out, bringing the lower extreme of the waveform to almost exactly 0V, by using a + and - dual supply for the LM358 and then replacing R3 with a 4k7 resistor in series with a 10k 22-turn cermet trimmer. Adjusting the trimmer would vary the output's dc level. You could test this in spice by varying the value of R3. Dual supply needed for LM358.